# Image blurs when resizing

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, resize

I'm trying to resize an image and display it into a picture box (64x64 px). The original image is 8x8 px but when I resize it to 64x64 pixels, it blurs. I don't see why, everything remains proportional. I tested using paint and the image resized without blur, so I just don't see why. Here is the code. Note that I first need to get the image from another image.

```
    Public Function GetPicturePart(ByVal SourceImage As Bitmap, ByVal Region As Rectangle) As Bitmap
    Dim ImagePart As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Region.Width, Region.Height)
    Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ImagePart)
        Dim TargetRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, Region.Width, Region.Height)
        Dim SourceRect As Rectangle = Region
        G.DrawImage(SourceImage, TargetRect, SourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    End Using
    Return ImagePart
End Function

Private Function SizeImage(ByVal img As Bitmap, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Bitmap
    Dim newBit As New Bitmap(width, height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBit)
    g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
    Return newBit
End Function

Private Sub AssembleSkin(ByVal Image As Image, ByVal Head As PictureBox, ByVal Body As PictureBox, ByVal LeftArm As PictureBox, ByVal RightArm As PictureBox, ByVal RightLeg As PictureBox, ByVal LeftLeg As PictureBox)
    Head.Image = SizeImage(GetPicturePart(My.Resources.james222, New Rectangle(New Point(8, 8), New Size(8, 8))), 64, 64)
End Sub
```

Comment: you have 64 source pixels, when you resize it, they have to fill the space of 4096 pixels, so of course it is blurry.

Comment: I see. So do you have any sugestions on how I could fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting (for a pixel enlargement):

```
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
```

other drawing modes:

```
e.Graphics.CompositingQuality
e.Graphics.CompositingMode
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode
```

also, may need GraphicsUnit.Pixel as a srcUnit param.